# Calculate big Theta bound for 2 recursive calls

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, big-o

T(m,n) = 2T(m/2,n)+n, assume T(m,n) is constant if either m<2 or n<2
So what I don't understand is, can this problem be solved using Master Theorem? If so how? If not, is this table correct?

```
level   # of instances  size    cost of each level  total cost
0              1        m, n            n                n
1              2       m/2, n           n               2n
2              4       m/4, n           n               4n
i             2^i    m/(2^i), n         n             2^i * n
k              m        1, n            n               n*m
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Master Theorem might be a little bit of an overkill here and your solution method is not bad (`log` means logarithmus to base `2`, `c=T(1,n)`):

```
T(m,n)=n+2T(m/2,n)=n+2n+4T(m/4,n)=n*(1+2+4+..+2^log(m))+2^log(m)*c
      =n*(2^(log(m)+1)-1)+m*c=Theta(n*m)
```

If you use the Master Theorem by treating `n` as a constant, than you would easily get `T(m,n)=Theta(m*C(n))` with a constant `C` depending on `n`, but the Master Theorem does not tell you much about this constant `C`. If you get too smart and inattentive you could easily get burned:

```
T(m,n)=n+2T(m/2,n)=n*(1+2/nT(m/2,n))=n*Theta(2^(log(m/n)))
      =n*Theta(m/n)=Theta(m)
```

And now, because you left out `C(n)` in the third step, you got a wrong result!

Comment: ah, I see. Thanks for the answer!